# Can I opt-out from receiving notifications from a particular post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

[What are the default text editors in different flavours of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913609/what-are-the-default-text-editors-in-different-flavours-of-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment1438884_913609)

I asked the above question today, received some great answers, accepted an answer. And it solved the initial problem that I had plus gave me some extra good knowledge/Information

## But

People are continuously commenting/ answering or improving their answers, which is good for community in general but I just want to opt out of receiving notifications of these comments. Can I turn of these notifications for single post?

---

*I'm calling red box and digits written inside as **notifications**, I hope they are called notifications*

Comment: I'm afraid there's not. Sorry :(

Comment: I left a comment asking people to stop commenting (and yes, I am aware of the irony). That might help.

Comment: @terdon can anyone do that? could I have done it without sounding rude?

Comment: Of course! It's your post, after all and you're the one getting all the notifications. As long as you're not rude when asking (don't say "shut up you morons! or anything), I see nothing wrong with leaving a comment.

Comment: @terdon they're not listening to you either https://askubuntu.com/questions/913609/what-are-the-default-text-editors-in-different-flavours-of-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment1439002_913609

Comment: I moved the comments to chat ad left a stronger comment. There's not much else we can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: I think that worked out, and I'm sorry for editing the post like hundred times

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh it was more like nine times, and it was okay

Comment: I think the answer is to change the site to allow people to opt out, or just not worrying about notifications.   I don't think I can commit to not commenting/improving questions/answers if I feel it's warranted.  It goes against the point of the site.  If a comment is a pointless "thanks" or whatever it's already not welcome.